# Submit de login e senha!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Estou com um formulário simples para fazer login de usuarios com login e senha...
Eu não estou conseguindo dar submit via JQuery, olha o código:

```
<div id="opcoes2">
<div id="fazerlogin2">
<form name="fazerloginform" id="fazerloginform" action="fazerloginform.php" method="post">
<input id="login" type="text" name="login" value="Login ou email">
<input id="senha" type="password" name="senha" value="Senha">
<span id="esqueceusenha">Esqueceu a senha ?</span>
<input id="entrar" type="submit" value="ENTRAR">
<div id="loginresposta"></div>
</form>
</div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fazerloginform").submit(function() {
            var login = $("#login").val();
            var senha = $("#senha").val();
            $("#entrar").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#loginresposta").html("Logando...");
            $.post('fazerloginform.php', {
                login: login,
                senha: senha
            }, function(resposta) {
                if (resposta != false) {
                    $("#fazerloginform").submit();
                } else {
                    $("#loginresposta").html("Login ou senha incorretos.");
                    $("#entrar").prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }, 'html');
            return false;
        });

 })
</script>
```

Estou usando a versão 2.1.1.js, da jquery, será isso ?
O erro que dá é que fica "Logando..." e para o script, não dá o submit!!!

Queria saber também qual a melhor maneira de login em php e mysql com jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo dois problemas aqui. Um deles é que você ainda tem o event handler ativo quando quer fazer o submit no script.

O event handler `$("#fazerloginform").submit(function() {` está a ser chamado quando você faz `$("#fazerloginform").submit();` dentro do success. Uma vez que o processamento é assincrono o código vai direto para `return false;` e o submi é cancelado, como se tivesse um `evento.preventDefault();`. Assim precisa de remover o event handler para fazer submit sem ser intercetado.

Teste assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fazerloginform").on('submit', function() { // usei .on() aqui, pois uso .off() embaixo
        var self = this;
        var login = $("#login").val();
        var senha = $("#senha").val();
        $("#entrar").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#loginresposta").html("Logando...");
        $.post('fazerloginform.php', {
            login: login,
            senha: senha
        }, function(resposta) {
            if (resposta != false) {
                $(self).off("submit"); // aqui remove o event handler
                $(self).submit(); // agora já pode fazer submit sem chamar este código novamente
            } else {
                $("#loginresposta").html("Login ou senha incorretos.");
                $("#entrar").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        }, 'html');
        return false;
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui alterando o submit para um click no botão de submit no form...:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#entrar").click(function() {
            var login = $("#login").val();
            var senha = $("#senha").val();
            $("#entrar").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#respostalogina").html("Logando...");
            $.post('fazerloginform.php', {
                login: login,
                senha: senha
            }, function(resposta) {
                if (resposta == true) {
                    $("#fazerloginform").submit();
                } else {
                    $("#respostalogina").html("Login ou senha incorretos.");
                    $("#entrar").prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }, 'html');
            return false;
        });

})
</script>
```

Ainda aguardo respostas.s...

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa usar `$("#fazerloginform").submit()` caso resposta seja true.
Veja se esse exemplo ajuda...

```
$('form[name="NOMEDOFORM"]').submit( function()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#respostalogina').html( 'logando...' );

    //
    $.ajax({
        url      : 'fazerloginform.php',
        type     : 'POST',
        data     : { login : $("#login").val() , senha : $("#senha").val() },
        success  : function( dataCheck )
        {
            if( dataCheck == false )
            {
                $("#respostalogina").html( 'Login ou senha incorretos.' )
            }
            else
            {
                // login feito
            }
        }
    });
});
```